# Is it appropriate to ask for more information from a questioner when reviewing even if I cannot answer the question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments

From time to time when reviewing questions, I find that I can spot that more information will be needed, even if I'm not technically competent to answer the question.

Example (using Zargon7 as a made-up language):

**New User (in question)**: When I run my code, which is written in Zargon7, I get the follow error:

```
<<Stack trace here>>
```

What should I do?

**Me (in comment)**: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you post the code which is causing the error?

Invariably, I'll get back something like:

**New User (in comment)**: I've posted the code... what's the problem?

**Me (in head)**: *facepalm*

Is it appropriate for me to ask for more information?  Is it likely to put others who can actually answer the question off from answering it?

Comment: Of course it is, your comment is helping to flesh out a good question that hopefully will be solved by someone, even if not by you.

Comment: Is it appropriate of me to do something obviously appropriate?  Why, of course not.  *Me (in head): **facepalm***

Comment: @Will Quite often, if I revisit a question that I've commented on, it's unanswered whereas if I revisit a question that I've not, it is answered.  I've not collected empirical evidence, but I had enough to get a feeling that I might not be doing the best by the questioner to engage on a question that I had no hope of answering.  The general view (from constructive answers :P ) is that it's worth improving the question.  I may have a delve into the stats/query bit to see if I can find some hard evidence one way or the other.

Comment: If you're worried that your comments pay be putting people off from answering, you can always delete your comment once the question has been improved. (Although really, it sounds like in most cases you'll be adding an upvote, removing a downvote, or revoking a close vote when you revisit the question, and it's hard to imagine a comment having more of an effect than any of those.)

Comment: Just today, one user prompted for information that another user used to help me. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/mysql-grant-requiring-additional-permissions I don't think it puts anyone off to have all of the information available. It may even help, as it lowers the barrier to answer, and they may not have pursued it otherwise.

Comment: Also, I'm amazed at how many programmers think "doesn't work" is an appropriate description for a problem...

Comment: Zargon7 is an awesome language, you should totally learn it!

Comment: You can't necessarily know that you can't answer the question if it is lacking information in a way that you can spot. The missing information might make it asnwerable by you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, of course that's good.

The review queue is about improving the content not deleting it (basically).

No, it's not going to put anybody off from answering. It often happens that I'm asking basic questions ("Did you try rebuilding?", "What does the file x.php contain?") and in the meantime somebody posts an answer. And nobody steps back from earning reputation just because somebody asked for clarification.

If the OP asks you directly to answer, ignore the user (there's no reason for excepting help from you, you already helped by clarifying the question!) or tell him that you can't help. But I recommend you to not take the last option because it just produces one more useless comment.

Comment: <useless comment> Thank you - I was worried it'd put others off from answering

Comment: @GHC Yes, it might put others off from answering, but most likely if they were going to answer a poor question, your comment stopped them by making them think twice about it.

Comment: Worth mentioning than comments are _not_ intended to work like ... say ... a "forum" where you engage yourself in a more or less exclusive conversation with the OP.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux That's what I meant by "useless comment" and "there's no reason for excepting help from you"

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's certainly possible to help someone improve a question (for example, by asking clarifying questions or for additional information) that you wouldn't be able to answer, even if improved, and you're more than welcome to do so if you want to.