# How to handle questions in review where questioner should provide more information?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

Regarding to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270638/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-more-information-from-a-questioner-when-reviewing-e) - which button should I use after asking for more information?

<kbd>Skip</kbd> or <kbd>Looks Ok</kbd> or <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you would suspect:

> **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

It says 'edits by the author', right? But if the outcome of the Triage review is Requires Editing, it will be sent to the Help & Improvement queue, where *other people* will try to make it a better question.

So the only option is <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> ->

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

If the author comes back later and edits the necessary information in the question, your flag will age away eventually.

Comment: a few months ago, I was banned from reviewing for a few day because a I flagged to much questions with _"requires editing"_ . I was told that this flag should only be used when the question can be improved *by the community* . I think this was correct. But every new reviewer should be informed when to use the flag _"requires editing"_

Comment: @JimHawkins I agree, and [178 other people do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues), apparently.