# How to handle English as a second language in review

Tags: support, review-queues, languages

I just started looking into the review queue and I've noticed a trend with a few of the questions. The questions look like they contain a lot of useful information but either through their grammar or their word choice it is obvious that the asker does not speak English as their primary language.

Should questions like these be marked as "Requires Editing" since some edits to the grammar would technically make the question more clear? Or should they be marked as "Looks OK" since the question is valid and the information supplied is complete and relevant? Or is there no clear cut rule and it just depends?

Comment: Related: [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/247702)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you can understand what is being asked, but it just takes a little bit longer to parse because of some minor grammatical errors, then you should mark it as "requires editing".  Fixing problems like this on questions that are fundamentally understandable/answerable, but could have better presentation, is literally exactly what the queue is for.

You should be using "looks okay" if there's nothing other community members could do to improve the question.

If the question's problems are so severe that it's just not even understandable, even with a bit of effort, then you should be voting to close it as unclear, not passing it off to an editor that won't be able to edit it into shape.