# What to do when other reviewers accept a low quality question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, review-abuse

While reviewing the triage queue, I saw [this very low quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544709/), and by getting back after tagging, I saw that two other users reviewed it as "Looks OK". IMHO, this cannot be accepted as such.

[image]

Is there anything I could/should do in that situation? Should I flag the question so it gets attention by a mod? Or is that overkill and I just let things go their way?

I reviewed as "Requires editing", to give this new user a chance, but I agree it could as well been have reviewed as "Unsalvageable".

Comment: You don't need to (should) flag for _mod attention_, there are enough reasons for flagging you have at hand.

Comment: "ha peeing" is possibly the greatest typo I've ever seen. I'm 12 years old mentally.

Comment: Wow, I hope that's not me. I would be feel bad if I'm in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should have been reviewed as "Unsalvageable", not "Requires Editing". This question is not answerable in its current state, and edits by users other than OP wouldn't help. See [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/3853934).

You should flag it using custom moderator flag and explain that some people reviewed this as "Looks OK" even though it should be reviewed as "Unsalvageable". Moderator are able to ban reviewers who don't review properly.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that. But AFAIK, if it gets tagged "RE" and the user doesn't, then it gets eventually closed. So as it was a new user, it's just a "give him a chance" sign. If he doesn't get how things work quickly, it will be closed anyway. But thanks for second part of your anwer.

Comment: And when I tag RE  this type of question, I always add a comment explaining what the OP should do.

Comment: @kebs "Giving a chance" doesn't work that way. If a question is not answerable in its current state, it should be **immediately** closed. During first 5 days after closing it's "put on hold", and during that time the OP can fix it, and it can get reopened. See [What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/310998)

Comment: ok, got that, thanks for those details. I'll lower my personal reviewing thresholds !

Comment: So long as the broken description remains, the person marking it as "Requires Editing" is doing what the description says.  Have they fixed the queue option description yet?