# Review option has been paused

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension

Today morning when I check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review) for reviewing questions, I am getting a message as preceding.

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14799638 incorrectly. Please read [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) and pay more attention to each review in future.Come back in 6 days to continue reviewing.

But if you can check, the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14799638) I made for that question is Require Editing as other users option. Isn't that correct. Please advice me if I am wrong, so that I can make sure that to not repeating that mistake in future. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you failed a review audit, and hence you are temporarily blocked from reviewing further.

Comment: @CinCout Thanks much for your comment, but I had given the option as `Require Editing` as two other users reviewed. Isn't that correct? Please advice.

Comment: Well, did you read the linked meta post?  (Also, this was a manual mod ban, so the other users who agreed with you were likely also banned.)

Comment: Never choose a reason because _"two other users reviewed"_ - if you are unsure then simply choose "skip"

Answer (score 15):

You were manually banned by a moderator (not me, but one of my colleagues) because you reviewed that item incorrectly. That question contains two parts: a code dump, then this:

> My coding error ,
>
> > comment sometimes photo parser. thank you! ı need you İD, photo id,
> >     video id, comment id and others.

It's not clear what this is, but it's not a clear error statement. It *looks* like a list of features for a "please give me teh codez kthxbye!1!!" request. It's also possible that it's just elaborate trolling. Whatever it is, **the question lacks a clear error statement and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).** This means it's off-topic unless and until the author fixes it to add that information.

From [the link in the ban message you saw](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674):

> **Do not** choose "Requires Editing" if you *know* the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author. For example, if an [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) question asks for an explanation of errors found in logcat, *but omits specific errors and/or logcat listing*, the question doesn't require editing - it requires more information, so choose *Unsalvageable->should be closed->unclear what you're asking*.

This question cannot possibly be improved by the community. It clearly needs editing *by the author* and therefore should be put on hold. That means reviewing it as "Requires Editing" was incorrect, and that's why you got temporarily banned from reviewing.

Also, just FYI: the fact that other users agreed with your review doesn't mean the majority was right. In this case, a majority of users got it wrong, and a ♦︎ moderator caught the mistakes.

I should point out that there are some problems with the Triage queue, as people have mentioned in the comments below. Most importantly, there is currently some inconsistency in the instructions to reviewers. The correct way to do reviews there is set out in the linked post from which I quoted. The system routes/handles posts based on that logic. But the on-screen instructions that appear if you click the "(help)" link when reviewing say,

> Requires Editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

That description is, frankly, just wrong, and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that the OP did the wrong thing by *following the instructions to the letter*.

Comment: @MacroMan See [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues) for background on the problem.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I've just noticed the quoted text in this answer is from something the user sees _after_ the ban - in which case it's too little too late. I'll delete my previous comment on that basis.