# Why is this question triaged "OK"?

Tags: discussion, triage

Going through "triage"; I was pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609143/after-login-into-website-unable-to-extraxt-tables-data-into-excel-using-vba).

My thought was: clearly "should be closed"; as it doesn't give any details about the "errors" the user is seeing.

But looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14862201) ... I am the only person coming to that conclusion. So 3 other people think that this question is at least "ok". OK, now its 2 against 3 ... after putting up this question here.

Now I am wondering: do *I* overlook something? Or them majority of other people?

Comment: A code dump and "It is not working" is not "Looks OK". I think that question can be saved, but it will need some input from the OP.

Comment: I think the reviewers in that queue see so much low quality stuff, they might be taken by surprise with this one...

Comment: @S.L.Barth I strongly **disagree**. *Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its **author**.* See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue

Comment: Saying "can be salvaged" in the comment was a bad choice of words on my part. Or maybe the button "Unsalvageable" should just be named "close". I think there is the potential of a proper question in there. But if only the OP can improve it, then "Unsalvageable" is the right button.

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised that the majority of people don't know how to review. These are the same people posting the low-quality garbage in need of reviewing. It doesn't help that [the system provides misleading and inconsistent information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues).

Comment: @CodyGray I am for sure not surprised; I **learned** the hard way last year that my review skills weren't exactly "great" too ... more than once. The main reason for me to put up this question was to get a confirmation on my assessment (or alternatively: learn why my assessment was wrong).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question should be closed, for the reason:

> "why isn't this code working?"

Two users thought it was OK (they made a bad decision), and one other thought it requires editing, which is also not the best action to be done in this case. I prefer to close it and reopen when and if the user edit it.

You did the correct action by VTC, but don't expect everyone to be perfect. Users who don't take enough time when reviewing, will fail the audit and be eventually banned.

Comment: I don't want other to be perfect. I just want to make sure that *I* made the correct decision - or to understand what I missed.

Comment: "other**s**" to be perfect that is. Pobody is nerfect as they say.

Comment: Nobody is perfect*. * except me.