# Failed audit after deciding for "requires editing", expected would have been "unsalvagable"

Tags: support

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15955449) and I don't entirely agree with the expected result for the audit. I read the first lines of the question and my first thought was "this is spam", but after reading further, there was a question. It wasn't a good question, but if the OP had posted what he tried so far (and removed the unnecessary description of TensorFlow), it could have been a valid question.

Leaving this special case aside, my question is: Is there a way to criticize audits so they get checked and maybe changed/removed? I'm not too familiar with the system and was curious if there is a way to mark an audit as "fishy".

Comment: @Tom no I meant the audit declared the right coice would have been "unsalvageable". I edited the title to clarify

Comment: Ok, the question title was ambiguous.

Comment: @gnat not really a duplicate, but related...

Comment: per my reading [answer in there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332727/839601) addresses your question. it explains that triage UI provides reference to FAQ guidance which explains in details why picking Requires Editing in your case is a wrong way

Comment: *is there a way to criticize audits so they get checked and maybe changed/removed?* Yes, come to meta like you did.

Comment: @gnat yeah but my question was if there is a way to mark an audit for a validity check

Answer (score 6):

There is no possible way that a community member could edit that question into a good question.  In addition to the fact that the first half of the question is just an ad for a product, and is unrelated to the question, the second half is both entirely lacking in any semblance of information necessary to actually provide an answer, and would be *way* too broad even if such information is available.  The question is unquestionably unsalvageable.  Deciding not to flag it as spam is something you can argue, but even if you don't consider it spam it needs to be closed.

Clearly this audit was doing its job quite well.

Comment: ok, just in case I ever have an audit I do not agree with and I'm not alone with this opinion, is there a way to request a check? You may be right, but you didn't answer the question...

Comment: @FlorianKoch It seems rather redundant to tell you that you can do something that you've already done.

Comment: ok, so the only way is to ask here? Then thanks for telling me. If you could edit your question to contain this I can mark it as answer