# Triage queue - Requires Editing vs. Too Broad

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

Having recently gained privileges for the basic Review Queues, I've been going through and am unsure when to use Requires Editing, and when to use Unsalvageable -> Too Broad.

I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096698/how-to-connect-android-apk-with-web-server) as Unsalvageable -> Too Broad, however the flag is still pending 5 days later, and the review was closed after getting 3 votes for Requires Editing, which makes me think my reasoning was wrong.

The question that was asked was:

> Hi i am new in android studio , my english is weak ,i want create chat android application (apk) i am using php mysql for send data to server by post method but when any one decompile my apk they can see my url plz give some idea for connect apk with web server

After questioned in the comments over whether OP wanted to know how to make a chat app or how to protect the app, he responded with `How to protect my app`.

From this, my thinking was that OP wants to know how to connect an Android app to a web server in a secure way, which I felt was too broad a question - there are many ways that this could be done, and there isn't a specific problem that's being asked about.

I was under the impression that Requires Editing was supposed to be for when someone *other* than the OP could edit the question, for example with spelling or formatting issues, and the [triage queue guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/1561469) says:

> **Do not** choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author.

It is unlikely that anyone can answer the question as-is without the OP editing it with more details on what they are trying to achieve, but the fact that there are 3 votes for Requires Editing, and that the flag is still pending after some time makes me wonder what the process is for which to choose. My question is, **should I have chosen Requires Editing instead of Unsalvageable -> Too Broad, and if so, when should Too Broad be used?**

Comment: That question is a  textbook case of "Too Broad". The reviewers who chose "Requires Editing" made the wrong choice.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks, I thought "Too Broad" was the obvious choice, but the other reviewers had me doubting myself!

Comment: Aside from reviewers making the wrong choice, anything under "unsalvageable -> needs to be closed" is going to take a while to get resolved, unfortunately. The "needs to be closed" queue is filled to the brim, per usual.

Comment: @CodyGray makes sense - I normally see my flags looked at one way or another within ~12 hours or so, so when this one was taking a while longer I thought I'd double check I wasn't doing the wrong thing. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: The other flags either immediately or eventually end up in the moderator flag queue, so they are guaranteed to get looked at. Sometimes our queue gets backed up, and it may take us a while to get to them all, but usually we resolve flags in 24-48 hours. Often it is even faster than that. The "needs to be closed" flags are different. Those are *only* reviewed by other community members, and the number of flags raised *vastly* outnumbers the number of available reviewers. That review queue is over 7k at the moment. It's been even higher recently.

Comment: That's not to discourage you from raising such flags. Please keep flagging questions that need to be closed! Just saying, you don't necessarily want to draw any conclusion about the accuracy of your flags just because no action is taken immediately.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for clearing all that up, I didn't realise the queues went to different people. You learn something new every day!

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/318307) on Meta.SE has a flowchart about queues and flags that you may find helpful.

Comment: @AndrewMyers very useful, thank you very much :)

Comment: Since this happened to me a not non-significant amount of times I'm slowly starting to question why the 'Requires Editing' flag even exists. If it does require editing, why not edit right there and then and flag it as 'OK'? Removal of that flag would solve this issue. Or at least rename it to something like 'Push question to 'Requires Editing' queue'.

Comment: You should note however that the reasoning you specified in your scenario about "OP clarifying his question in comments" is not valid all the times. It is possible that review has been done before comments are entered (I am not talking about this specific question) so there is a possibility that when you read comment and picked "too broad" others marked it with some other reasoning.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Right. It's not available outside the triage. If I can't flag a topic with 'Requires Editing' right away then why is it there?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You reviewed correctly. The question is crap and should be closed as "too broad" or "unclear".

> I was under the impression that Requires Editing was supposed to be for when someone other than the OP could edit the question

This is correct. You should use "requires editing" for questions that have spelling, grammar or formatting issues but are otherwise ok and on-topic.

People constantly picking "requires editing" for questions that should be closed is a bit of a known issue with the triage queue.

Comment: "I was under the impression that Requires Editing was supposed to be for when someone other than the OP could edit the question" Require Editing could also be used for post that should be edited by author. Refer this description. "Requires Editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable"

Comment: And in that case, it is really confusing what flag to choose. If question is too broad, one can ask author to edit it in comments and Skip. Most of the time, author will never edit it and post will keep hanged up.

Comment: @AmitJoshi: See: [Adopt a consistent policy on what “Requires Editing” means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/2127008)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Lundin, just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing the wrong thing and end up getting review banned for it!